# Which license should I choose on arxiv.org for later publication?

Tags: arxiv, license, creative-commons

I wrote an opinion piece for a journal but it was rejected.

I would like to put it on arxiv.org because now I do not have time to rewrite it, but I would like to circulate it. And, there are more important things to do. But, at some point I would like to submit a rewritten version to another venue. Which license should I choose on Arxiv?

https://arxiv.org/help/license

Comment: I don't think you have given us enough information to make a significant choice.  But in general if you're unsure it's probably best to go with the minimal non-exclusive license.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that all listed Creative Commons licenses allow the distribution of the paper in modified forms? If I do not want that, the first option allows only Arxiv to distribute the paper in unmodified form, right? Then that's my choice.

Comment: @Gergely No, not all CC licenses permit modification: https://creativecommons.org/about/cclicenses/

Comment: @user2768 I meant the listed ones that Arxiv allow

Comment: Note that some venues may refuse a paper that has been posted to arXiv at all, regardless of what license was chosen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there are two factors you will usually take into account:

1. The policy of the journal or journals you expect to submit the work to.  You must choose a license that is permitted by that journal.  You can easily determine what is allowed using [Sherpa/Romeo](https://v2.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/).  Just search for the journal and look at what is allowed for "submitted version" (or accepted version) in a subject repository.
2. Your own preferences.  This is straightforward -- read the license and make sure you agree with what it allows/doesn't allow.

When in doubt, the minimal non-exclusive license is the safest bet: https://arxiv.org/licenses/nonexclusive-distrib/1.0/license.html